# Write a function based on given TestUnit

Tags: function, reverse-engineering

I need to write a function to satisfy this input -> output list:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
5 -> 5
7 -> 13
9 -> 34
```

f(x) = ??

Comment: If you fill out f(x) for x in {2, 6, 8} you may find that the sequence is easier to spot.

Also, homework questions (and this looks very much like one) should be tagged homework.

Comment: what does this have to do with unit-testing or reverse-engineering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is incredibly easy... if you aren't concerned about **over-fitting**, then you can do:

```
switch(input)
     case 0: report 0
     case 1: report 1
     case 3: report 2
     ...
     default: report whatever
```

You probably need more constraints on the problem if you want a good solution. You also might consider graphing the function to see if there is any obvious pattern, or maybe show the bits involved. It would also be useful to know if the inputs and outputs are integer-valued or real-valued (is the function supposed to be continuous or discrete?). Without this information, it's a little bit hard to help.

**Edit**
Showing the missing numbers helps:

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
**2 -> 1**
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
5 -> 5
**6 -> 8**
7 -> 13
**8 -> 21**
9 -> 34

(It's the Fibonnaci numbers: f(x) = f(x-1)+f(x-2), where f(0)=0 and f(1)=1).

**PS**
This is a function for which [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) or memoization is particularly useful.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework problem or a puzzle and he wasn't given the missing numbers to make it more difficult (e.g. to defeat [OEIS](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html?q=0%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34&language=english&go=Search))

Comment: @Robert, if you want to invoke the function many times or if you want to return the result for a wide range of values, then dynamic programming will save you from redundant computation. Even if you invoke the function once, the use of the recursive formula f(x-1)+f(x-2) causes both forks to repeat computation unnecessarily. With dynamic programming, prior results are kept such that f(i) is not computed more than once for any given value i during the computation of f(x).

Comment: This answer has been accepted, one presumes, on the basis of [YAGNI][1]. It would not work very well for `x` > 9.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI

Comment: @Johnsyweb, what? I don't think you got my meaning... it was a joke... there are an infinite number of possible functions that have the given output for the given example inputs (because, for the unspecified inputs, you could output any possible value). You need to assume that there is an UNDERLYING PATTERN; without this assumption, you can just memorize the example input/output pairs and return whatever the hell you want for the remaining inputs.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: I certainly got your joke. I don't think that @TiuTalk did, though :-)

Comment: @Johnsyweb, in that case, I'm confused... what did you mean by your comment about YAGNI?

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: [Before the edit] you provided just enough code to satisfy the requirements and no more.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by [Eureqa](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/eureqa)

`round(exp(0.4807*input - 0.799938))`

Comment: @Robert That's probably true, but it doesn't make his answer wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is homework or not, but this is an extremely well-known sequence. A (rather large) hint is that f(n) is dependent on f(n-1) and f(n-2). If you're not concerned with just being told the answer, [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence). Implementing the sequence is pretty trivially done recursively, but edit your post if you're having trouble with it and specify which part you're stuck on